# Javascript won't run in masterpage

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, master-pages

In my masterpage i have placed the ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" inside the head tags and the ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" inside the body tag. When I'm using the code without masterpage, it works fine. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable = no" />
<link href="styles/basic.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="scripts/jquery.responsivetable.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setupResponsiveTables();
    });

    function setupResponsiveTables() {
        $('.responsiveTable1').responsiveTable();
    }
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" RowStyle-Wrap="false" CssClass="responsiveTable1"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" DataKeyNames="id" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Stilling" HeaderText="Stilling" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Fornavn" HeaderText="Fornavn" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Etternavn" HeaderText="Etternavn" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Telefon" HeaderText="Telefon" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        </Columns>

<RowStyle Wrap="False"></RowStyle>
    </asp:GridView>      
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Move the setupResponsiveTables function After the GridView inside the MainContent

Comment: @Max moving the function didn't work

Comment: There are errors of the browser console ? Have you checked the class of the grid on the browser after render ? Add the following code to the end of the gridView `<script>$('.responsiveTable1').responsiveTable();</script>`

Comment: @Max I added "function setupResponsiveTables()" along with that code. Now it works perfect! Thank you :-)